# Is there anyway to resolve the Built to Last quest without handing over the Forge Knight plans?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

The Built to Last quest requires me to hand over plans for Forge Knights to the crucible knights. However, creating Forge Knights requires bonding the souls of people to armor. The character I'm roleplaying is a benevolant fellow, so binding souls to armor isn't exactly something he'd approve of. I was hoping there would be a way to resolve this quest without turning over the plans, but I can't seem to find one, but I'm hoping I missed something.

Is there anyway to resolve this quest without turning over the Forge Knight Plans? If not, are there any consquences to turning over the plans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to the point - according to [wiki information](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Built_to_Last) that looks solid enough (as it contains in-game IDs of quest stages) there is no other way of finishing this quest.

That said there are consequences of turning over the plans - the quest chain will have one more part, and give you an opportunity to speak your mind. Not huge, game-spanning consequences mind you, but good enough I'd judge.

The process looks like this:

> After initial success which you witness while returning the plans knights start mass-production. Next part starts after some time - or possibly just leaving and going back to the district.

and in the next part:

> As you come back you notice that, of course, soul-bound armors are in berseker mode and need to be put down. After some moping Knight Commander (whatever his name and rank actually is) has some doubts at which point you get the option of speaking your mind about the whole idea and what to do next.